# How to fix duplicate flash alert messages using Devise in Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise to handle user authentication. When a user signs up, I am seeing 2 flash messages displaying the same text.

The blue well I believe is rendered through my application.html.erb:

```
    <!-- Notice -->
    <% if notice %>
        <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
            <center><%= notice %></center>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

However, I am unable to figure out where the 2nd message comes from. Any advice on where I should ook?

[image]

Comment: Do a global search on `notice`. The only logical explanation is that it is duplicated (either in your `application.html.erb` or in one of your views)

Comment: Didn't know how to do global search...found the issue! Do you want to make this answer so I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may be using simple_form_for. That gem takes care of the error notice.